# How does eclipse know the name of your project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a fully working project (lets say its called "mygame") on disk which contains multiple activities. The activity which gets called first is called "launcher". I wish for the project to be called "com.mycompany.mygame", but when I do an import project in eclipse and select the root directory of my project, a dialog appears stating that the project that is located at this directory is "com.mycompany.mygame.launcher" with no way of changing it. My question is, what is eclipse using to determine that my project has the name "com.mycompany.mygame.launcher"? Is it something in the manifest?

Comment: Is this package name anywhere in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Right near the top it says: package="com.mycompany.mygame"

Comment: The import function has been revamped since one of recent ADT upgrade (r20 if I recall) and does not allow you edit project name at project import phase anymore. If you keep .classpath and .project with you source, you can use `File - Import.. - General - Existing Projects into Workspace` import your project which will pick up <name> from .project as default project name. the con is this Eclipse generated .classpath and .project may not work when cross different OS or Eclipse version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the eclipse takes the class name which extends *Activity*. Because when u extend any other package like the Fragment etc., it won't create the by default Launcher for that particular class. So whenever the Class name with manifest point to launcher will get imported along Or it will attach the class name. with the package name

Answer (score 8):

Did you mean the project name changed? If that, you can check the `.project` file that is located in your project's root folder.

Comment: The ".project" file contains a line <name>mygame</name> and certainly doesn't contain the text com.mycompany.mygame.launcher so I am still none the wiser :-(

Comment: Can I understand like this: Your project name is `mygame`, and the default package is `com.mycompany.mygame`. But when you import this project to eclipse the default package changed to `com.mycompany.mygame.launcher` ? If so, Is there a folder whose path like `%PROJECT_ROOT%/src/com/mycompany/mygame/launcher` or `%PROJECT_ROOT%/launcher` ?

Comment: Ther is no "launcher" directory. The ".java" files are all in %PROJECT_ROOT%/src/com/mycompany/mygame/

Comment: If you confirm that the configure in `.project` `.classpath` and `AndroidManifest.xml` are all correct, please try create a new clean eclipse workspace and import `mygame` project. I doubt it's a special environment issue.

Comment: I meet this issue recently, the steps I used are `File-->Import-->Android-->Existing Android Code Into Workspace`. Then I found it's not a good idea to import android project, and It will use the main activity as project name. You can use `File-->Import-->General--> Existing Projects into Workspace` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to your problem, when I try `Import` -> `Android` -> `Existing Android code` into workspace the naming is off.

For those who commented and were confused about the question, what is happening is that Eclipse imports the project as the name of the first activity (including the namespace).

It imports the project as com.company.app_name.first_activity_in_the_manifest

I have been having this problem for a while.  I found the solution for my project.  Because it is a git repo, I have to do `Import` -> `Git` - > `Projects from Git` -> `local`.

Then it imports correctly, and doesn't have the side effect of some solutions mentioned here, importing existing code into a new project (which would probably remove my link to the git repo).

Answer (score 4):

in eclipse, right click your project Android Tools -> Rename Application Package ,  change the name to com.mycompany.mygame

Comment: That may be valid - but doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: why it's not answer your question?, please provide more details

Comment: Actually I have multiple packages that I move from one PC to another, I don't want to have to do the renaming process over and over if I can fix it once and for all... Also I have had so much aggro with eclipse in one way and another, that the more I can find out about how it works the better I will cope when things go wrong in the future. Also I'm just curious.

Comment: If your question is really about moving projects, you should ask it that way. The proper way to move projects is to use *File* > *Export* and *File* > *Import*. Or better yet, use a scm system like cvs, svn, or git. Eclipse projects contain some configuration data about the project that is useful for moving a project to another workspace; Android projects have even more than normal Java projects. Export/Import takes care of including that data.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using eclipse 'import existing project to workspace' feature?

You should use 'New Android Project -> Create Project From Existing Source' feature.(I don't know how these options exactly appear in your eclipse, so you'l have to find them) In this way you can rename it to anything.

**Your Second option could be:** Import existing project to workspace (as you are doing already). Leave the name of the project as it is, then **after completing the import process, you can rename the project to whatever you want**.

Answer (score 3):

In your manifest file the name attribute in manifest tag will show the package name.Also the package explorer view in eclipse will show the package name.For example if your pkg name is com.cmpny.game,then your src folder will contain src>com>cmpny>game> foldersa and inside it will be your code saved.

Answer (score 3):

In every Project there is file called **`.project`** which is responsible for project name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>PROJECTNAME</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
     ........
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    ....../natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 3):

The name ADT displays in the Package Explorer may not be the name in the .project file.  To change this, right click on the name -> Refactor -> Rename.  Change the name with "Update References" checked.  Make sure the name you want is unique to your Package Explorer listing.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because of directory structure followed for all applications of same types, as all the application contains some files/folder on the root folder that is the name of our application e-g android project contains files like  `.project` and `.classpath` and folders like `.myeclipse src bin .settings` etc

Answer (score 1):

In the projects directory there is .project file created by eclipse ! when we import the project is searches for this file and collects the project related information from this file. That's how its done. If u delete this file just for the purpose of checking eclipse will no more recognize that directory as a project !