# How to fix issue when I import Android project to Eclipse I get package name instead project name?

Tags: android, eclipse

Sometimes, when I try in Eclipse (JUNO) to import Android project from existing source I get in list instead Project Name - package Name. For example instead project named `MyProg` i get `com.demo.agent.datasrc.MyMainClass`. How can I fix it?

I tried to rename folder name and `.project` file  its works but its messy workaround.

Please, help

Comment: Import as `Existing project to workspace` instead of android project. You probably need to set android build target after that.

Comment: Yep, thanks, interesting why they use Android folder only for Existing Code.Thanks

Comment: Add link to [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177713/how-does-eclipse-know-the-name-of-your-project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wenhui: "Import as Existing project to workspace instead of android project. You probably need to set android build target after that"